# How to know why a transaction was rolled back?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions

I have an `Account` model. It has usual `validations` and `after_save` callbacks. There is a requirement, and account objects are to be created following some additional validation strategy. I have the following snippet, which works fine:

```
def special_account_creation
  Account.transaction do
    a = Account.create(params)
    resp = update_third_party(a) # Throws exception if unable to update
    validate_amount(a, resp)     # Throws exception if `a` is invalid
  # rescue Rollback ??? <--- How to do this
  #   msg = <transaction_error_details>
  # Rails.logger.info("Special Account not created due to: #{msg}")
  end
end
```

`a` account is destroyed if anything goes wrong while calling a third party API or during validation.

I want to know how I can log the error to know why the transaction was rolled back.

Comment: Did you see [this link](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Rollback.html)?

Answer (score 4):

`ActiveRecord` transaction catches any exception being raised inside and rolls back the transaction. After that, if the exception is `ActiveRecord::Rollback`, it is supressed otherwise any other exception is raised above the call stack.

Ref: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Rollback.html

So you could do something like this:

```ruby
Account.transaction do
  begin
    a = Account.create(params)
    resp = update_third_party(a) # Throws exception if unable to update
    validate_amount(a, resp)     # Throws exception if `a` is invalid
  rescue StandardError => e # <- assuming all errors need to be logged
    Rails.logger.info("Special Account not created due to: #{msg}")
    raise e # <-- Don't forget to raise the error!
  end
end
```

I suggest raise the error from the rescue block - this will rollback the transaction and if the error is something other than `ActiveRecord::Rollback`, it will be raised outside the transaction block. These errors you can handle in [rescue_from block](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#method-i-rescue_from) in base controller.

Also prefer catching `StandardError` and not `Exception`: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rescue-standarderror-not-exception

I am assuming we want to catch all possible errors in that block, hence the use of `StandardError`, otherwise use any specific errors that need to be intercepted.

Comment: You should actually be caching something far more specific than `StandardError`. This will still catch things like a `NoMethodError`. I would suggest rescuing from `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` instead. http://wiki.c2.com/?PokemonExceptionHandling

Comment: @max I am assuming that we want to log all possible errors occurring in that block - hence catch all. I have edited the answer accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveRecord` does not raise `Rollback` on failed update and/or failed validation.

You should rescue what was raised and then there are two opportunities: either raise `Rollback` to just rollback a transaction and continue normal execution flow, or re-raise what was raised to indeed break the normal flow.

```
def special_account_creation
  Account.transaction do
    a = Account.create(params)
    begin
      resp = update_third_party(a) # Throws exception if unable to update
      validate_amount(a, resp)     # Throws exception if `a` is invalid
    rescue => e # might be more specific    
      Rails.logger.info("Transaction failed with a message #{e.message}")
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, e.message # just to rollback
      # raise e # for re-raising the exception
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The `update_third_party` and `validate_amount` method already log in case they throw exception, so I don't think there's any benefit in adding same log again.

Comment: oh, I got you. So, should I rescue only `StandardError` (default) or all Exception ? I've read that rescuing Exception is a very bad practice. In that case how should I log what went wrong in transaction?